# No styles in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

Created a div with a unique class applied to it in the file bootstrap unique styles, but when the page loads, they disappear. How to understand that their erasure and fix it?

```
.slider-container {
height: 100%;     
position: absolute;         
z-index: -11; 
}
```

My site is - http://tourlly.com/new/

Comment: What disappears?? I can see the page fine.

Comment: Not related, but note that you have double `rel` on the favicon tag: `rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: Styles to .slider-container disappear - here picture - https://st.free-lance.ru/users/Om/OmgOwnedByGirl/upload/f_99351ff855f50195.png in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQLRR.png
in your CSS. Check it. And try use validator for markup

Comment: Thanks it's solution!